# Faster way to iterate through range

Tags: c++

I'm a competitive programmer, and I've been asking myself if there is any shorter, more elegant way of writing`for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)` . I can only use standard C++, no other libraries.

Comment: About the title, I meant 'faster way of writing ...'

Comment: I've been thinking about something similar to the `for i in range(0, n):` from python.

Comment: It is not clear how you intend to use `i`. If you'll use it for indexing in, let us say `const char s[] = "abc";`, you could write `for (auto c : s);`

Comment: I want to use it like this: `for(auto i : {0, 1, 2, (...), n-1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ competitions there is well known set of macros (don't use it in commercial projects). You also asked for more elegant solution (it is well known solution, but for sure not more elegant)

For example read this [topcoder](https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=features&d2=020807) website:

```
#define REP(x, n) for(int x = 0; x < (n); ++x)
```

then in code you can simply write

```
REP(i,n){
}
```

One basic complete header I found:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> VI;
typedef long long LL;
#define FOR(x, b, e) for(int x = b; x <= (e); ++x)
#define FORD(x, b, e) for(int x = b; x >= (e); – –x)
#define REP(x, n) for(int x = 0; x < (n); ++x)
#define VAR(v, n) typeof(n) v = (n)
#define ALL(c) (c).begin(), (c).end()
#define SIZE(x) ((int)(x).size())
#define FOREACH(i, c) for(VAR(i, (c).begin()); i != (c).end(); ++i)
#define PB push_back
#define ST first
#define ND second
```

Comment: Well, some of them are quite outdated, but the idea is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Without running timed tests, I would assume that both:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

and:

```
int i=0;
while (i<n)
{
    i++
}
```

would be extraordinarily close in timing.  Perhaps use timestamps within a program that runs both types of loops, and see what the overall time/loop is for each type.

These are the fundamental looping structures of C / C++, so I do not think there would be something that would run faster (but I'm willing to be wrong if I learn something new)

Comment: The only mechanism I can think of off the top of my head that would be faster is **goto _label_**.  But that is a very nasty can of worms, and has to be dealt with as such.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent to my python for example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  If there is, I'm sure someone will speakup on the thread relatively soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you didn't specify whether you need to use `i` how about[1]:

```
int i=n+1; while(--i);
```

Its shorter!

[1] not proven to be correct.

Comment: If you use `i` but backwards is OK, it is better to use `for(int i=n;i--;)` so at least the correct set of values of `i` are used (as long as `n` is non negative)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a competitive programmer too. This answer may be off-topic, but I think it will provide some useful ideas.

Personally, I think you shouldn't focus on these types of questions. I don't think there's a big difference between writing `for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)` and `FOR(i, 1, n)`. The first one is obviously shorter and takes less time to type, but once you get to a high enough level, problem-solving skills matter much much more than typing speed. Don't trust me? See tourist's code.

I think what you should focus on is improving your problem-solving skills. The best way is to solve as many problems as possible. Doing so will also increase your typing speed as a side effect.